# List all classes that inherit from a specific class/interface

Tags: c#

I have an assembly, and I want to list all classes that inherit from a specific class/interface.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetSubtypes(Assembly assembly, Type parent)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(type => parent.IsAssignableFrom(type));
}
```

That's fine for the simple case, but it becomes more "interesting" (read: tricky) when you want to find "all types implementing `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T`" etc.

(As Adam says, you could easily make this an extension method. It depends on whether you think you'll reuse it or not - it's a pain that extension methods have to be in a non-nested static class...)

Comment: I got Skeeted, as usual. Might as well make it an extension method, too.

Comment: @Jon, How would you do if "you want to find "all types implementing IEnumerable<T> for any T" etc."? Also you said "it's a pain that extension methods have to be in a non-nested static class". Why? Do you use nested classes often. Thanks.

Comment: @Joan: I'd need to know whether it was finding an implementation of a *particular* `IEnumerable<T>` or *any* `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. is T specified or not?) As for extension methods... I don't tend to write many top level static classes. Creating one just for extension methods is a bit of overkill.

Comment: I made a slight correction as follows :)
  private IEnumerable<Type> GetSubType(Assembly asm , Type parent)
  { 
   return asm.GetTypes().Where(type => parent.IsAssignableFrom(type));
  }

Sorry, I can't figure out how to do the code block in the comment.

Comment: @Jon: well, don't thank me now. I thought I had what I wanted but still not working :(    I should have said I made a change. That way it wouldn't have sounded like I fixed something.

Comment: @Jon: I place extension methods in a class named *ThisType*`Extensions`, so the above would be in `AssemblyExtensions`. For being inherently difficult to keep track of, that certainly helps out.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesThatInheritFrom<T>(this Assembly asm)
{
    var types = from t in asm.GetTypes()
                where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                select t;
    return types;
}
```