# How to get List of classes, inheriting from one class and one interface / or instead from two interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, c#-7.3

I want to create a List of default descendant instances of a base class. What I already can get is a `List<Type>` or `IEnumerable<Type>` of those descendants.

Base class and descendants are self made. So I understand them very well.

Is C# Framework already providing a smart way for this?

This is what I got:

```
    public static List<Type> GetList_Descendants(Type baseClassType, string assemblyName)
    {
        return Assembly
        .GetAssembly(baseClassType)
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseClassType))
        .ToList(); // Otherwise return would be of type IEnumerable.
    }

    public static void Add_AllDescendants<T>(this List<T> emptySource, List<Type> descendants)
        where T : new()
    {
        emptySource.AddRange(???);
    }
```

---

### Descendants of a class && an interface

*stop-cran* already gave me an answer, about how to get descendants of a class given by generic type. (See first answer below and first two comments.)

---

### Descendants of two interfaces

How can I get descendants of two interfaces instead?
 This is what I did, its working:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Assumes, that there are two interfaces and classes inheriting of both - all placed in the same assembly.
    /// 1st interface is IStrategy. 2nd interface is described by generic type.
    /// 
    /// Creates an IEnumerable of all available Func'IStrategy' child instances which are of generic type, too.
    /// Thus one decouple creation of such a IEnumerable from creating the child classes of type IStrategy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Func<IStrategy>> GetByInterfaceBaseType<T>() =>
    typeof(T)
    .Module
    .Assembly
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => (t.GetInterface(typeof(T).FullName)!= null)
             && (t.GetInterface(nameof(IStrategy)) != null))
    // We assume T has a parameterless constructor
    .Select(t => (Func<IStrategy>)(() => (IStrategy)Activator.CreateInstance(t)));
```

Here is a link, which might be also interesting for you:
[List all classes that inherit from a specific class/interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287892/list-all-classes-that-inherit-from-a-specific-class-interface)

For me, this case is solved. But good advises are always welcome!

Comment: The problem here is even if one impose the `where T : new()` constraint on a base type, it is not guaranteed that all its descendants follow it, i.e. have a parameterless constructor. What aim are you trying to achieve? In general it's more convenient to use dependency injection, relying on inherited interfaces, than on the class hierarchy.

Comment: I want to create some kind of factory, to walk trough all strategies (descendants) relating to a base class. All descendants will have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the question comments, I'd propose to have an `IStrategy` interface and use `IEnumerable<Func<IStrategy>>` to inject list of strategy factories (here I use delegate factories for brevity, one can use an interface instead). Thus one decouples creation of such a list from creating the strategies:

```
static IEnumerable<IStrategy> CreateAll(this IEnumerable<Func<IStrategy>> factories) =>
    factories.Select(factory => factory());
```

Sample usage:

```
listOfStrategies.AddRange(
    new Func<IStrategy>[]
    {
        () => new B(),
        () => new C()
    }).CreateAll()); // 2 items (`B` and `C`) will be added.
```

In case if it's convenient, one can create the list of strategy factories (`Func<IStrategy>`) from the class hierarchy:

```
static IEnumerable<Func<IStrategy>> GetByBaseType<T>() =>
    typeof(T)
        .Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)) && t.GetInterface(nameof(IStrategy)) != null)
        // We assume t has a parameterless constructor
        .Select(t => (Func<IStrategy>)(() => (IStrategy)Activator.CreateInstance(t)));
```

A sample:

```
class A { }

class B : A, IStrategy { }

class C : A, IStrategy { }
```

Creation of the strategy factory list:

```
var factories = GetByBaseType<A>().ToList(); // Two `Func<IStrategy>` objects
var strategies = CreateAll(factories).ToList(); // Two `IStrategy` objects - `B` and `C`.
```

Also a method that returns `IEnumerable<T>` in general is more reusable and "pure" than a method that takes `List<T>` and adds items into it.

One more thing - many DI containers supports resolving a list of all registered implementations. See [`UnityContainer`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container/) example below:

```
var c = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<IStrategy, B>("B")
    .RegisterType<IStrategy, C>("C");

// Two items - `B` and `C`.
c.Resolve<IEnumerable<IStrategy>>().ToList();
```